# Rate limiting in nginx not working as expected

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting

In our application one particular endpoint is receiving duplicate requests which results in some transactional lock in the DB, as it is not possible to give a new build now, we are trying to handle it at nginx level for the time being using rate limit. The expected behavior is that if there are multiple POST requests to the endpoint /api/disp from a client within one second then only one request should be allowed. Below is the nginx configuration, but it is not limiting the requests, as I can see two requests from same client being forwarded instead of limiting. Is there something wrong in this config? I am not able to find anything wrong in it.

```
map $http_x_forwarded_for $client_ip {
    default         $remote_addr;
    "~^([^,]+)"     $1;
}

map $request_method $limit {
                        default         "";
                        POST            $client_ip;
}


limit_req_zone $limit  zone=deduplication:10m rate=1r/s;



 location /api/disp
                {
                proxy_pass http://10.12.12.12:8080/api/disp;
                limit_req zone=deduplication;
                limit_req_status 503;
                proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
                proxy_set_header X-TENANT-ID  "ccc";
                proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
                proxy_send_timeout 600s;
                add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
                proxy_cookie_path /api "/api; Secure;SameSite=none";

                }
                ################################
                location /api
                {
                proxy_pass http://10.12.12.12:8080/api;
                #limit_req zone=deduplication;
                #limit_req_status 503;
                proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
                proxy_set_header X-TENANT-ID  "ccc";
                proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
                proxy_send_timeout 600s;
                add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
                proxy_cookie_path /api "/api; Secure;SameSite=none";

                }
```